# Browser caches the redirect url. How can I prevent it from being cached?

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I'm using nginx to rewrite a url

```
rewrite ^/old$ /new1 permanent;
```

I need to change the address that /old redirects to (/new1) every few days. I noticed that when I change the /new1 url to /new2 and restart nginx, browser still redirects to /new1 untill I clear browser cache.

How can I prevent browser from cacheing redirection url?

P.S. The reason I need to keep changing the url is that I have a banner set up on one of the sites and in order to not bother the site owner with new url all the time, I though I'd give him one address to use and keep changing my redirection myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not use permanent redirections. The code should be:

```
rewrite ^/old$ /new1 redirect;
```